# pass a command to another cmd window when starting it with the start command

Tags: c++, c, cmd

I'd like pass a command to another cmd window when starting it with the start command. For example, I'd like to be able to type something like `start cmd dir` where the dir command is run in the new window. Unfortunately the way I wrote it, it doesn't work. I'd like to run this task in a c/c++ program; however, that command can be run easily by typing the command into the `system("start cmd dir");` function

Comment: @kaylum I just added the command to the system function, the progam will only make the one call. Imagine that command being in the main function with nothing else but a return 0; below it

Comment: `start cmd /K dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "windowtitle" cmd /c dir
start "windowtitle" cmd /k dir
```

- `/c` Run the command and exit
- `/k` Run the command and continue reading commands interactively

For more complicated commands, use doublequotes, for example:

```
start "windowtitle" cmd /c "dir && pause"
```

This can be also written as

```
start "windowtitle" cmd /c dir ^&^& pause
```

because `^` literalizes the next character, and prevents the original `cmd` seeing `&&` as a command separator.

Comment: awesome, it works. I'll mak the answer as right in 10 mins, it won't let me do it right away.